Converting py to exe - dll issue
I coded multiple script for a retro gaming app on VSCode and it works perfectly in .py. However, converting with auto_py_to_exe leads to it not working when I try to display the score table.
686226 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'LIBPQ.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\Broua\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\PySide6\\plugins\\sqldrivers\\qsqlpsql.dll'.
686243 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'MIMAPI64.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\Broua\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\PySide6\\plugins\\sqldrivers\\qsqlmimer.dll'.

and I have this error when trying to access the score display table : unread result found
I added qsqlpsql.dll and qsqlmimer.dll - didn't work
I put them in hidden import - didn't work
I excluded them - didn't work
In my script I only use mysql.connector, the is no postgresql so I do not get it.
Here is the method the clicked button activate when the .exe suddenly close :
def go_table_display(self):
    self.create_database()  # Ensure the database is created or opened

    self.model = QStandardItemModel()
    self.checkbox_myscoreOnly = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Only show my scores")
    self.checkbox_myscoreOnly.setStyleSheet(self.common_style_checkBox)
    self.model.setColumnCount(5)  # 5 colonnes pour les résultats (Date, Player Name, etc.)
    self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Date", "Player Name", "Game Played", "Score", "Game Time"])
    # Récupérer les scores et les ajouter au modèle
    self.scores = self.set_scoreDisplay()
    if self.scores:
        self.model.setRowCount(len(self.scores))
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(self.scores):
            for column_index, value in enumerate(row_data):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))  # Convertir les valeurs en texte
                self.model.setItem(row_index, column_index, item)  # Ajouter les valeurs au modèle

    # Set aesthetics for the database view
    self.aestetic_database()

    header = self.table_view.horizontalHeader()
    header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)

    # Create a new window for displaying the table
    self.table_window = QtWidgets.QWidget()  # Initialize the window first
    self.table_window.setWindowTitle("Game Results Table")
    
    header_length = self.table_view.horizontalHeader().length()
    total_width = header_length + 70  
    
    self.setMinimumWidth(total_width)
    self.adjustSize() 

    self.back_gamechoice_fromtable_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BACK TO GAME CHOICE MENU")
    self.back_gamechoice_fromtable_btn.setStyleSheet(self.common_style_btn)
    self.back_gamechoice_fromtable_btn.setMaximumWidth(400)
    self.back_gamechoice_fromtable_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_gamechoice_menu)
    self.stats_fromtable_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("STATS")
    self.stats_fromtable_btn.setStyleSheet(self.common_style_btn)
    self.LowbtnLayout_TableDisplay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.stats_fromtable_btn.setMaximumWidth(180)
    self.LowbtnLayout_TableDisplay.addWidget(self.back_gamechoice_fromtable_btn)
    self.LowbtnLayout_TableDisplay.addWidget(self.stats_fromtable_btn)
    self.stats_fromtable_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_stats_display)

    # Create a layout for the table view inside the new window
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.table_window)

    layout.addWidget(self.table_view)
    layout.addWidget(self.checkbox_myscoreOnly, alignment= QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    layout.addLayout(self.LowbtnLayout_TableDisplay)        
    # Set layout to the table window
    self.table_window.setLayout(layout)
    self.checkbox_myscoreOnly.stateChanged.connect(self.update_score_table)

    # Add the table window to the stacked layout and display it
    self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.table_window)
    self.stacked_layout.setCurrentWidget(self.table_window)

def set_scoreDisplay(self):
    cursor = None
    try:
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        
        # Exécuter la requête en fonction de l'état de la case à cocher
        if self.checkbox_myscoreOnly.isChecked():
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE NAME = %s", (self.player,))
        else:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM RESULTS")
        
        self.scores = cursor.fetchall()  # Récupérer les scores
        return self.scores
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Database Error: {e}")
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self, "Database Error", f"Error retrieving scores: {e}")
        return []
        
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()


Which python version are you using and do you have the build log of the executable?this should help others better answering your question.
